# How to set multiple markers in leaflet using textbox as dataset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Good day!
I just wanna ask, How can i set multiple markers after putting coordinates in textbox and display it in leaflet map?

[Please see image Thank you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnCXj.jpg)

After i put coordinates in textbox, and once i click submit button, it will display a marker and put again another coordinates and click submit and display again another marker.

Thank you very much!

Comment: On the click event of the button, parse the contents of the text box into coordinates and create a marker with them. Add the marker to the map. Have a go at implementing it and post your results. SO works best when you show your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Highly appreciated.